# Cloud init execution by custom user

Tags: cloud-init

As far as I know, by default **cloud-init** is executed by the **root** user. Is it possible to set a custom user with sudo access to execute?

Comment: anyone? I am also interested in this topic, this far I didn't find any hard evidence, but it seems that cloud-init requires root privileges.